# Onrefresh indicator is not working in conditional statement

Tags: dart, flutter

I have `Scaffold` which contains a body with condition to render different components. I have added `onRefreshIndicator()`. But it is not working when `Text` is rendered and working completely fine when list `NamesList` get rendered.

I have tried separating two components in different files but then also it is not working.

```
`body: Container(
     child: RefreshIndicator(
           child: fetched && names.length == 0
                ? Text('Not able to fetch')
                : NamesList(names, widget.value, widget.header),
           onRefresh: () => getJSONdata(widget.value),
     ),
)`
```

I expect that `onRefreshIndicator()` should work in both the condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your `Container` widget to have the max height available and put your `Text` widget inside a `SingleChildScrollView` with `AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics`.

```
Container(
   height: double.infinity,
   child: RefreshIndicator(
            child: fetched && names.length == 0 
              ? SingleChildScrollView(
                  physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                 child: Text("Not able to fetch"))
              : NamesList(names, widget.value, widget.header),
            onRefresh: () => getJSONdata(widget.value),
            ))
```